# Can't resolve all parameters for Component when dependency is registered within a service via providedIn option?

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, angular2-providers

I've been playing with DI in Angular and can't figure out why I run into an error when specifying a service to be provided in module via `providedIn`.

First off, I created `SharedModule`, declared there `SharedComponent` and configured `SharedService` as follows:

```js
// shared.module.ts

@NgModule({
  declarations: [SharedComponent],
  exports: [SharedComponent]
})
export class SharedModule {}

// shared.service.ts

@Injectable({
  providedIn: SharedModule
})
export class SharedService {
  prop = Math.random();
}
```

Then I added one lazy module, included `SharedModule` into `imports` property on `NgModule` decorator factory of both `AppModule` and `LazyModule` and configured my routing strategy. Here is the setup:

```js
// app.module.ts

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'eager', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'eager', component: SharedComponent },
  { path: 'lazy', loadChildren: './lazy.module#LazyModule' }
];

const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    routing,
    BrowserModule,
    SharedModule
  ],
  declarations: [AppComponent, EagerComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  providers: [{provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/'}]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

```js
// lazy.module.ts

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: SharedComponent }
];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forChild(routes);

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    SharedModule,
    routing
  ],
})
export class LazyModule {}
```

As a result, I get the following error:

> Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for SharedComponent: (?).

But if I comment `providedIn: SharedModule` and declare a provider for the `SharedService` within the `SharedModule` it works like a charm:

```js
// shared.module.ts

@NgModule({
  declarations: [SharedComponent],
  exports: [SharedComponent],
  providers: [SharedService]
})
export class SharedModule {}
```

Please see the [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/dsafsadfwefpoewqfwqef-prsdzb?file=app%2Fapp.module.ts) demo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I ran it locally on my machine it gave me `console.warn` saying there is a circular dependency.

> Circular dependency detected: src\app\shared.component.ts
>   -> src\app\shared.service.ts -> src\app\shared.module.ts -> src\app\shared.component.ts

I fixed it as describes this [guide](https://medium.com/@tomastrajan/total-guide-to-angular-6-dependency-injection-providedin-vs-providers-85b7a347b59f) by adding additional module intended for the service. So it's best not to rely on StackBlitz when it comes to debugging.